# Interim Blank Page while loading in GWT production mode

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I do have a Java/GWT web application with quite weird behavior while loading in IE 11.

1. (Good)Page loads fine in chrome
2. (Good)Page loads fine both in chrome and IE-11 in hosted mode
3. (Good)Page loads fine in IE-11 if the browser debugger wizard is launched (tried to debug it using a debugger)
4. (Problem)Page loads with interim blank page in IE-11

Since the page loads fine if the browser-debugger is enabled  and also loads fine in hosted(development) mode, I really had  hard time replicating the issue while debugging. any hint or experience with IE 11 on such scenario is appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a job for Super Development Mode. There isn't enough information to actually drill this. But I'd start looking initializing of the application, using logging to walk through all the steps of setup. I start by looking for exceptions, then uncaught exceptions. Then I start looking to see if it's a layout issue, maybe it's there with a height issue. Maybe it's doctype...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to disable an option in IE to show our GWT App.
There are settings for compatibility mode. We have to disable "show intranetsites in compatibility mode".
Our systems are not in english so names may be different.